# Retrieve photo from Sql Server to asp.net & Vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is in vb.net
  The photo never show up and I have no error....???

This is how I stock the photo on The SQl DB

```
    Sub StartUpLoad()

    Dim imgName As String = FileUpload1.FileName
    Dim imgSize As Int32 = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength
    Dim photo As Byte() = New Byte(imgSize) {}
    Dim user As String = "kdjhkjgh"




    If FileUpload1.PostedFile IsNot Nothing AndAlso FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName IsNot "" Then
        If (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 100240) Then

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(Page), "alert depuis le codehind", String.Format("alert('{0}')", "Fichier trop gros"), True)
        Else
            Dim connectionString As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BecsEtMuseauxSQL").ConnectionString
            Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("dbo.addPost", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@titre", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBoxTitre.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxDescrip.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = photo

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()




            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(Page), "alert depuis le codehind", String.Format("alert('{0}')", "Post sauvegardé"), True)

        End If

    End If


End Sub
```

This my handler

```
Public Class Handler : Implements IHttpHandler

Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest


    Dim connectionString As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BecsEtMuseauxSQL").ConnectionString
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

    ' Create SQL Command 

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "Select Titre,Image from Post where ID =@IID"
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = con

    Dim ImageID As New SqlParameter("@IID", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
    ImageID.Value = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString("ID"))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(ImageID)
    con.Open()
    Dim dReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    dReader.Read()
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(DirectCast(dReader("Image"), Byte()))

    dReader.Close()
    con.Close()

End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property
```

End Class

This is my  asp data grid

```
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Titre" HeaderText="Titre" SortExpression="Titre" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
                <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
                  ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "Handler.ashx?ID={0}")%>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ControlStyle Height="200px" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image">
            </asp:ImageField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BecsEtMuseauxSQL %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BecsEtMuseauxSQL.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Titre], [Image] FROM [Post]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Do you have any idea why my photo never show up???

Thanks for helping me!!!

Comment: Instead of storing image in table, may be you should store the image path(directory)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you response doesn't know what type of binary data you are sending (by default it is text/html). Try to set ContentType to "image/jpeg" (exactly, there must be your image file MIME). 
If you download different image types it is better to store into table Post its MIME in your addPost procedure (you may use FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType property for this purpose) and use it in handler.

Answer (score 0):

you can use context.Response.ContentType property to mention file details, so that browser can serve basic needs to rendering.

```
context.Response.ContentType=ImageFormat.Jpeg;
```