# ASP.NET- Gridview not display image

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="bookname"  Height="504px" 
        Width="289px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="image">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
                        ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("~/path/to/image/" + Eval("image")) %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("image") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="bookname" HeaderText="bookname" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="bookname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="price" SortExpression="price" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [image], [bookname], [price] FROM [books]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My Image field is saved in   (SQL server 2005)...and image inserted in database through file upload button  ... 
and now i want to  show data in gridview but not display image field and other field shown in gridview very well becauese other fields are text format.

Comment: i think problem is there ImageUrl='<% %>'....but i cnt solve that problem ...please help me for this code

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string qry;
        string connection = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\WebSite1\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataSource sds = new SqlDataSource();
        qry = "select * from books";
  
        sds = new SqlDataSource(connection, qry);
  
 GridView1.DataSource = sds;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    }

Comment: are you saving the image path into the database?

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("~/path/to/image/{0}" , Eval("image")) %>' />
```

Your Problem was that `string.Format` accepts arguments and you were using a concat operation. Here i have used `{0} - stands for argument at/for index 0`. Similarly for multiple arguments you can use `string.Format("{0} {1} {2}",var1,var2,var3).`

Also above i am assuming {0} will be replaced by file name with extension , like abc.png.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="bookname"  Height="504px" 
            Width="289px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="image">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
                            ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("~/path/to/image/{0}" , Eval("image")) %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("image") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="bookname" HeaderText="bookname" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="bookname" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="price" SortExpression="price" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [image], [bookname], [price] FROM [books]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect rather something like

```
ImageUrl='<%# this.ResolveUrl("~/path/to/image/" + Eval("image")) %>' />
```

rather than `string.Format`

Comment: Use an http debugger (Fiddler) to see the actual request uri.

Comment: any other option ...can you tell me for showing image in gridview ...what things are do for that ..like add column for image field and
somewhere i read that ~/images/{0} ?? for imageurlform ...what is this?

Comment: I don't see any flaw in your approach. You just have to debug the request and see the status of the server response. In Fiddler you will see everything: is the request sent (or not), does the server processes it and what exact response is sent to the client. Most probably you just get 404 Not Found because of the mistyped uri.

Answer (score 0):

As your image is stored into database, you need to use a handler to retrieve the image. You can get a referance here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/271590/Show-an-image-saved-in-a-SQL-Table-on-an-ASP-Net-I

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875568/retrieve-photo-from-sql-server-to-asp-net-vb-net